# можно ли сделать чтобы в режиме isProduction не создавался devServer?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

У меня есть два режима, isProduction и isDevelopment, могу ли я поставить тернарный оператор на devServer, чтобы когда режим isProduction, dev сервер не создавался? или это бесмысленно и он и так не создаться?

```
module.exports = (env, { mode }) => {
  const isProduction = mode === 'production';
  const isDevelopment = mode === 'development';

    devServer: {
      port: 3000,
      // https: true,
      historyApiFallback: true, // для чего узнать?
      // proxy: {},
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго времени суток.

Для начала нужно определить правильный запуск в `package.json`. А именно добавить следующее

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --open --env NODE_ENV=development",
    "build": "webpack --env NODE_ENV=production"
  },
```

После чего, вернуться в `webpack.config.js` и там прописать следующее

```js
module.exports = (env) => {
  const production = env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

  return {
    mode: production ? 'production' : 'development',

    devServer: {
      static: {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
      },
      port: 3000,
    },

    devtool: production ? false : 'source-map',
  }
}
```

Готово. Теперь при запуске `npm start` ваш проект будет запускаться в режиме `dev`, а при запуске через `npm run build` в режиме `prod` и не будет запускаться сервер

Comment: тестировал если сделать npm run build без ваше защиты, получается devserver не запускается тоже

Comment: не могли бы пожалуйста подсказать, когда делаю билд у меня не создаётся сервера когда делаю dev создаётся, умеет ли вебпак сам решать когда создавать или не создавать сервер?

Comment: @Виктория. Не совсем понял последнее. У вас при старте в режиме prod, не запускается сервер?